# Supercede null results in stored procedure and VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, stored-procedures

I wrote a simple stored procedure that I can't seem to override null return values.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[rt_sp_rstk_OpticComplete]
    @serial varchar(50) OUTPUT,     
    @remaining int OUTPUT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    UPDATE [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[RESTOCK_OPTICS]  
    SET [SELECTED] = 'False', 
        [COMPLETED] = 'True' 
    WHERE [SERIAL_NUMBER] = @serial     

    UPDATE [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[RESTOCK_JOB_QUEUE] 
    SET [QUANTITY_REMAINING] = [QUANTITY_REMAINING] - 1 
    WHERE [SELECTED] = 'True'   

    SET @remaining = (SELECT [QUANTITY_REMAINING] 
                      FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[RESTOCK_JOB_QUEUE] 
                      WHERE [SELECTED] = 'True')

    RETURN ISNULL(@remaining, 0)
END
```

I've tried validating the procedure with `IF NULLIF(@serial, '') IS NULL` for good measure but it doesn't seem to matter.  The issue is the function 'can' be executed (edge case) inadvertently.  I can't really avoid it because I'm using the function in multiple directions, so the best thing I can do is simply return a '0' when the select statement results in a null.

```
Function restockOpticComplete(serial As String) As Integer
    Dim remaining As Integer
    Dim opticSerNo As String

    errorPosition = "queryForOptics.restockOpticComplete"
    On Error GoTo errorTrap
    Err.Clear

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    constr = "Provider=sqloledb;data source=i.p.add.ress;initial catalog=CATALOG;user id=USER;password=PASS"
    conn.Open constr
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "rt_sp_rstk_OpticComplete"
        .CommandTimeout = 2
        .NamedParameters = True
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@serial", adVarChar, adParamInputOutput, 50, serial)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@remaining", adInteger, adParamOutput, , 0)
        .execute
    End With

    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Restock\activeOpticSerial")
    eTag.Value = ""
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Restock\activeOpticStack")
    eTag.Value = 0
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Restock\activeOpticTray")
    eTag.Value = 0
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Restock\activeOpticPosition")
    eTag.Value = 0
    remaining = cmd.Parameters("@remaining").Value
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Restock\activeJobRemaining")
    eTag.Value = remaining

    restockOpticComplete = remaining

    GoTo cleanExit

cleanExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    conn.Close

    Exit Function

errorTrap:
    LogDiagnosticsMessage "Restock.gfx, Position: " & errorPosition & " , Error Code: [ " & Hex(Err.Number) & "], Description: " & Err.Description & ""
    Resume cleanExit

End Function
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Ahh missed the VBA part...so what is the actual question? You are having an issue with something but I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: @SeanLange Although I an using ISNULL, I still get null values.

Comment: You are using the remaining value but in your code you are not setting it to not be null. You are instead returning a number. The easiest fix is to change the word "RETURN" to "SELECT". They way it is coded you would need to check RETURN_VALUE but honestly using an output parameter is the preferred method for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try put the ISNULL condition after "set @remaining =" ... something like this.

```
            ALTER PROC [dbo].[rt_sp_rstk_OpticComplete]
                @serial varchar(50) OUTPUT,     
                @remaining int OUTPUT
            AS
                SET NOCOUNT ON
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[RESTOCK_OPTICS]  
                SET [SELECTED] = 'False', 
                    [COMPLETED] = 'True' 
                WHERE [SERIAL_NUMBER] = @serial     

                UPDATE [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[RESTOCK_JOB_QUEUE] 
                SET [QUANTITY_REMAINING] = [QUANTITY_REMAINING] - 1 
                WHERE [SELECTED] = 'True'   

                SET @remaining = ISNULL((SELECT [QUANTITY_REMAINING] 
                                  FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[RESTOCK_JOB_QUEUE] 
                                  WHERE [SELECTED] = 'True'),0)

                RETURN @remaining
            END
```

TEST

```
                --- test 1
                CREATE PROC [dbo].[rt_sp_rstk_OpticComplete_test]
                    @val INT,  
                    @remaining int OUTPUT 
                AS
                    SET NOCOUNT ON
                BEGIN
                    SET @remaining = @val
                    RETURN   isnull(@remaining,0)

                END

                GO

                DECLARE  @remaining INT 
                EXEC [dbo].[rt_sp_rstk_OpticComplete_test]null,@remaining OUTPUT

                SELECT @remaining

                GO

                DROP PROC [dbo].[rt_sp_rstk_OpticComplete_test]
                GO

                --- test 2
                CREATE PROC [dbo].[rt_sp_rstk_OpticComplete_test]
                    @val INT,  
                    @remaining int OUTPUT 
                AS
                    SET NOCOUNT ON
                BEGIN


                    SET @remaining = isnull(@val,0)
                    RETURN  @remaining
                END

                GO


                DECLARE  @remaining INT 
                EXEC [dbo].[rt_sp_rstk_OpticComplete_test]null,@remaining OUTPUT
                SELECT @remaining

                GO

                DROP PROC [dbo].[rt_sp_rstk_OpticComplete_test]
                GO
```

Result:

```
        -----------
        NULL

        (1 row(s) affected)


        -----------
        0

        (1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I'll play with this when I get back to this part of my code.  I could swear I already tried it but who remembers :P